# Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes in PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, .net

Im trying to replicate the following in php although i am stuck at Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(paramList)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string paramList = "paramList=ThruDate_" + thruDate.ToString() + "|OwnerLevel_" + ownerLevel;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(paramList);
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Close();
```

Comment: I find it worrying that you're using Encoding.ASCII despite the fact that even the hard-coded part of your string uses non-ASCII characters (the first one).

Comment: its funny you know.... it is actually "paramList=  but it shows up as non ASCII for some reason in Internet Explorer....

Comment: It's not "paramList" in the question text. I don't know how it got messed up, but it's definitely not ASCII here...

Comment: Let's just assume it is "paramList" and fix the question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to get an array of bytes in order to send POST data to some http server when using php.

```
$postdata = "something=something";
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'POST'
        'content'=>$postdata,
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    )
));
$responsedata = file_get_contents('http://...', false, $ctx);
```

see also:
http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents
http://docs.php.net/context.http